# Missing "Figure" title for captions of side-by-side graphics

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, subfloats

### Background

Trying to reference the label of figures that are side-by-side.

### Problem

Referencing figures by their label works, except when the figure is in a mini-page. That's when the word "Figure" does not appear in the output:

[image]

### Preamble Source

The preamble is at: http://pastebin.com/Uq1sGrSd

### LyX Source

The code LyX generates is:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
\subfloat[\label{fig:Design-Flower-Title-Page}Title Page]{\includegraphics[width=8.89cm,height=6.281cm]{captures/template-flower-title-01}

}%
\end{minipage}\hfill{}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
\subfloat[\label{fig:Design-Flower-Design-Page}Design Page]{\includegraphics[width=8.89cm,height=6.281cm]{captures/template-flower-title-02}

}%
\end{minipage}

\caption{Title and Detail Pages}

\end{figure}
```

### Related

[Line up captions on side by side figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/line-up-captions-on-side-by-side-figures)

### Question

What needs to change in the preamble so that the "Figure" label appears when referencing side-by-side graphics?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not tell us which referencing command and which subfigure package you use (there's no such package in your preamble).

I guess you use `subfig` (because of `\subfloat`) and `\autoref`. This would explain the behavior and can be fixed by

```
\newcommand*{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}
```

---

Btw. `hyperref` is the first package in your preamble, it should be the last one (besides some exceptions).